# Did the Oracle corrupt Agent Smith?

Tags: the-matrix, agent-smith

By the final battle between Agent Smith and Neo in *The Matrix Revolutions*, Smith had taken over the Oracle, so the resulting hybrid must have been influenced in part by the Oracle.

Evidence which suggests this:

1. At the beginning of the final battle, **Smith claims to know the outcome of the fight**, something only the Oracle would have a chance of knowing

> Neo: It ends tonight.
>
> Smith/Oracle: I know it does – I’ve seen it. That’s why the rest of me is just going to enjoy the show – we already know that I’m the one that beats you.

But then Smith becomes scared and doesn't understand what is happening

> Smith/Oracle: Wait… I’ve seen this. This is it, this is the end. Yes, you were laying right there, just like that, and I… I… I stand here, right here, I’m… I’m supposed to say something. I say… Everything that has a beginning has an end, Neo.
>
> {Neo begins to get up again}
>
> Smith/Oracle: What? What did I just say? No… No, this isn’t right, this can’t be right. Get away from me!
>
> Neo: What are you afraid of?
>
> Smith/Oracle: It’s a trick!
>
> <sub>***The Matrix Revolutions***</sub>

2. Smith is overconfident in his abilities, as **only one Smith fights Neo**, as opposed to all Smiths (which we assume Neo could not have defeated from his battle with Smith in *The Matrix Reloaded*). This suggests Smith knew he would defeat Neo, so this is closely related to point 1.
3. Once Smith is killed, the **Oracle lies where Smith was defeated**. So the Oracle was part of Smith during the whole battle.

[image: The character 'the Oracle' as played by Mary Alice.]

My theory, which goes beyond the scope of this question, is that the Oracle orchestrated a lot of what happened in the Matrix trilogy; guiding humans to imbalance the Architect's equations, which ultimately led to peace between humans and machines (a goal most likely in line with the Oracle's motivations given she was developed to understand the *"human psyche"*)

**Did the Oracle corrupt Smith by giving him false premonitions that he would win?**

If so, this ultimately led to Smith's defeat, due to his false sense of security.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## No; Smith just hadn't *understood* his choices yet

### Me, me, me... Me too

OracleSmith had foreseen the events of the final fight in *Revolutions*, he tells his copies to stand back and watch, and tells Neo:

> I’ve seen it. That’s why the rest of me is just going to enjoy the show

The Oracle within OracleSmith has no more say in what Smith does or says as any other 'captive' of Smith's. Remember the part where SatiSmith says:

> Cookies need love, like everything else does

And the fact that later on, he buggers up the planet's weather system. This shows that Smith has all of the memories and abilities of Sati, yet is in full control of what is said.

### You've already made the choice, now you just have to *understand* it

At some point toward the end of the fight though, Smith's 'visions' of the future reach up to the point where he can no longer *see past*:

> **Smith:** I stand here, right here, and I'm supposed to say something. I say, "Everything that has a beginning has an end, Neo."

> What? What did I just say?

Smith hasn't yet realised the reality of his choice to destroy Neo; to him, that's the end game, whereas in 'reality', that's merely the equation balancing itself out.

The 'scene' or vision that Smith had would have been him standing over Neo, defeated, in a pit. He would have *assumed* that's the end, and that he finishes the job there, having won.

In reality though, that is not the finale of the act; we later learn that it is in fact the point where the two coalesce and balance out the equation, thereby fulfilling the function of The One. This is what Smith doesn't understand, that he is merely the other side of the same coin.

### You have the sight now

You see, Neo, having offered himself to the Source (Deus Ex Machina) and entered the Matrix to do exactly *that* shows that he had in fact understood his choices, and did in fact have 'the sight' as The Oracle tells him.

---

To answer your specific questions:

1. `Did the Oracle corrupt Smith by giving him false premonitions that he would win?`
   **No**, OracleSmith saw the exact scene that happened, this was not faked in any way by the Oracle. OracleSmith was just too inexperienced with prophecies<sup>#</sup> and too overconfident in his ability.
2. `Smith is overconfident in his abilities, as only one Smith fights Neo, as opposed to all Smiths (which we assume Neo could not have defeated from his battle with Smith in The Matrix Reloaded)`
   **No,** Smith *is* overconfident in his abilities, but Neo escaping Smith's grasp in *Reloaded* is not indicative of Neo's failure. In fact, it is not evident what would have happened had Smith succeeded in 'copying' himself onto Neo at that point (or any other point for that matter). It's just as safe to assume that they both would have been terminated and the equation balanced.  
   In fact, in the final fight, Neo doesn't actually 'beat' Smith (at least not in the traditional sense), he lets Smith take him over, thus becoming Smith's undoing.
3. `Once Smith is killed, the Oracle lies where Smith was defeated. So the Oracle was part of Smith during the whole battle.`
   **Yes,** she was there the whole time, but there's no evidence to suggest that she had any control over what happened. She was merely a host to the virus.

---

#:

> Prophecy is like a half-trained mule. It looks as though it might be useful, but the moment you trust in it, it kicks you in the head. -[GRRM](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_prince_that_was_promised#cite_note-Radwd40.7B.7B.7B3.7D.7D.7D-17)

Comment: Now don't make me quote the *other* GRRM quote about prophecies.

Comment: Perfect answer! I see the results of this final battle as a tactical victory for Smith but a strategic (and hence, "all that matters") victory to Neo, Oracle and the System. BTW, this quote by GRRM is indeed beautiful. Thanks for quoting!

Answer (score 4):

Smith did win however in winning he copied himself over Neo which balanced the equation

The oracle states at some point that you cannot see past a choice you do not understand which is why Smith could only see his victory and not what would happen after he overrode Neo